# The complex ABNF rule converts to a regex

Tags: regex, abnf

This is hard to me. How to convert below ABNF rule to a regex?

```
*((*LF *CR *(\x0 / text) *CR *LF) / CRLF)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((\n*\r*(\x00|text)*\r*\n*)|\r\n)*
```

Assuming
1. The `*` after `text)` was a typo
2. You meant `/` rather than `|` (a pipe separates alternatives in regular expression, but in ABNF you need to use a slash).

It wasn't that hard. In regular expressions, a pipe is used rather than a slash, and quantifiers are postfix instead of prefix. Whitespace is not ignored, unless you're in free-spacing mode which you can switch to by using the `/x` modifier. [It's probably better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581037/can-pcre-regex-match-a-null-character) to use `\x00`, even though `\x0` will probably work as well.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed the typo.