# Search null terminating characters in Mongo Database v3.0.11?

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre, aws-documentdb

We have a number of strings in a MongoDB instance that include null-terminating characters, and we need to find which ones those are. Knowing that Mongo uses PCRE Regex, we found ([Can PCRE regex match a null character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581037/can-pcre-regex-match-a-null-character)) the correct syntax for matching a null-terminating character and searched for it like so:

`db.updates_v2.find({'longDescription': /.*\x00.*/ }).count()`

However, this returns `0`. We know for a fact that there are null terminating characters in there because during a migration to DocumentDB, it refuses to accept them. Also, we've run the following query that confirms that `longDescription` is the culprit:

```
db.updates_v2.find().forEach(function(doc){
... for (var key in doc) {
...     if ( /.*\x00.*/.test(doc[key]) )
... print(key)
... }
... });
longDescription
longDescription
longDescription
...
```

I've also tested the regex in Node (albeit a different regex engine):

```
> test = "wot wot in the \0"
'wot wot in the \u0000'
> test2 = "wot wot in the wat"
'wot wot in the wat'
> regex = /.*\x00.*/
> test2.match(regex)
null
> test.match(regex)
[ 'wot wot in the \u0000',
  index: 0,
  input: 'wot wot in the \u0000',
  groups: undefined ]
```

This is an issue when migrating from mongodb to aws-documentdb as the latter will not accept \0 characters in strings.

We really need to be able to reliably pull these out, in order to create a script that can `find` the offending entries, strip the null chars and `update` the entries. Any ideas?

Comment: Since this has seen some views lately: We never found a solution to this and it prevented us from migrating away from MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in a MongoDB server 4.4.16 shell:

`db.updates_v2.find({"longDescription": {"$regex": "\\0"}})`